# Two dimensional discrete uniform distribution

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution

I was wondering... Is there any formula for a two dimensional discrete uniform distribution? I've googled a little bit but I don't seem to find anything... I hope that somebody can help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have an $m \times n$ grid of points and you want a PMF (probability mass function) which gives the probability of  drawing a certain point.  Since you have $m\cdot n$ points in total and you want the mass function to be uniform that means for each $i \in \{1,\dots,m \}$ and $j \in \{1,\dots,n \}$,

$$
P(X = x_{i,j}) = \frac{1}{m \cdot n}.
$$